# How to use Cursor with Objectify

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

The title may not be accurate so let me describe exactly what I need to do:
I have a database of people. I need to display them to user youngest first. Imaging it's an android app with a ListView (or imagine a website, whatever helps). So for the first call I send 50 items to the caller. When the caller scrolls, I want to send another 50; and so on. So my method below accepts the `int index` parameter. But I am not sure where to put it. Naturally I want to use `startAt` but that method is expecting a cursor. Here is my code below

```
public static Collection<Person> getYoungestKids(int index){
        return OfyService.ofy().load().type(Person.class).order("-dob").limit(50).list();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out this example to work with Cursors. Using Offsets is considered to be very expensive. You should always use cursors for pagination.

https://github.com/objectify/objectify/wiki/Queries#cursor-example

Comment: Thanks for the link. +1. Could you please explain the queue portion inside the `if(continu)` block? I don't understand why it's needed. I am using google cloud endpoint: so my app-engine is a module in an android project.

Comment: Couldn't I simply return `cursor.toWebSafeString()`? As opposed to adding it to a queue? What's the queue for? and why add a url to it?

Comment: I think I get it. I cannot test yet. But I am reading https://rominirani.com/google-cloud-endpoints-tips-5-using-cursor-and-limit-parameters-20d3e8865ac3#.urcm2nwc6 and it seems to help.